# newbie node.js bot integration with database lookup (looking for best practice)

Tags: node.js, botframework

OK, new to Node.js and botframework.  I built first bot using Azure site and downloaded the code.  Chose the Luis integrated bot template.

I understand (finally) the event driven model of node.js and the concept of callbacks.

I have the code snippet below.  When Luis finds an intent of "Help" it triggers this function.  In turn, I have database calls to lookup the entity.  Within the database I have an entity, response (if entity is bottle, answer "Recycle").

I have that code working too.

Below the first block is a function handleHelpRequester which is the callback function, I have that working as well.  Where I am a little stuck (best practice) is that in this callback function I want to send something to the session object (session.send toward the bottom of the function).

Since I don't create the session object (directly) I'm not sure on the options.
Should I pass the session object to the database function, then pass it back?

Should I create a global variable and set it to the session object (I'm concerned that if multiple people are using this bot then this approach won't work).

I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks

```
.matches('Help', (session, args) => {
            var entities = args.entities;
            var itype = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'ItemTypes');


     var respondToUser = '';
        var msg = 'Initialized';

        // if there is an entity provided, perform a lookup of the entity.
        if (itype.entity !== null) {
            //Use session.sendTyping so the user thinks something is happening rather than being ignored while we do the lookup in SharePoint.
            session.sendTyping();

            //perform lookup
            respondToUser = sp.lookupEntity(itype.entity, handleHelpRequest);
        };
    })

function handleHelpRequest(err, respondToUser) {
    var msg = 'uninitialized';
    if (err = 'success') {
        console.log('Respond to user from matches:'.concat(respondToUser));
        //return from lookup
        if (respondToUser === 'No match found') {
            msg = 'I think you are asking for help, but I don\'t understand what you need help with.';
        }
        else {
            msg = 'I can help you with that, \'%s\'.', respondToUser;
        }


        console.log(msg);
        session.send(msg);

        //The following two lines are for debugging
        session.send('How may I assist you? ' + JSON.stringify(args));
        session.send('Value of entity you said:  \'%s\'.', itype.entity);
    }
    else {
        console.log('an error occurred');
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works dont touch it. First rule of nodeJS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have access to the session object, then pass it as a parameter to your helper function.

Example:

```
function handleHelpRequest(session, err, respondToUser) {
    // do session stuff
}
```